# How to find and replace instances with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to reformat some data that I have that isn't playing well when I copy text from a pdf.

```
Cordless
9B12071R
CHARGER, 3.6V,LI-ION
Cordless
9B12073R
CHARGER,NI-CD,FRAMER
Framing / Sheathing tools
F28WW
WIRE COLLATED FRAMIN
Framing / Sheathing tools
N89C-1
COIL FRAMING NAILR
Framing / Sheathing tools
N80CB-HQ
```

I want to have it formatted like this:

```
Cordless      9B12071R     CHARGER, 3.6V,LI-ION
Cordless      9B12073R     CHARGER,NI-CD,FRAMER
....
```

What I'm trying to do is a find and replace that replaces the first two new lines "\n" with a tab "\t" and leaving the third "\n" in tact.

The first thing I do is replace all "\n" with "\t" which is easy. After that, I want to replace the third "\t" with "\n". How would I do that using regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For EditPadPro, paste this into the `Search` box

```
([A-Za-z /]+)
([A-Za-z0-9_-]+)
(.*)
```

Paste this into the `Replace` box

```
\1  \2  \3
```

And that should do it. Basically you can add carriage returns and tabs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> in EditPadPro.

I had to add a carriage return to your text in the question as it's missing the last line I think. All the others are in triples of data.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work just by copying and pasting your regex, but I can't recreate it. I had to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. Holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't do anything.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys but I don't think it works in comments. Yes Shift+Enter/Tab also works for inserting those characters. I've just always had Ctrl work for me. Glad it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Alright here is the php code that does ***exactly*** as you want:

```
<?php
   $s = "Cordless
   9B12071R
   CHARGER, 3.6V,LI-ION
   Cordless
   9B12073R
   CHARGER,NI-CD,FRAMER";

   $p = '/(Cordless.*?)\\n(.+?)\\n(CHARGER.+?)(\\n|$)/s';
   $r = '\\1' . "\t" . '\\2' . "\t" . '\\3' . "\n";

   echo preg_replace($p, $r, $s);
?>
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
>php -q regex.php
Cordless        9B12071R        CHARGER, 3.6V,LI-ION
Cordless        9B12073R        CHARGER,NI-CD,FRAMER
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this a regex job or can you rely on the line number?

```
$ perl -nE 'chomp; print $_, $.%3? "\t": "\n"' file
```

**EDIT** (after comment)

If you have to do this in an editor, then this works in vim:

```
%s/\(.\+\)\n\(\C[A-Z0-9-]\+\)\n\(.\+\)/\1^I\2^I\3/
```

The important bit here is the assumption that a line that consists entirely of `A-Z`, `0-9` and `-` constitutes a part number. `^I` is a tab, you type *tab* and vim prints `^I`. (I hope your editor has this many steroids!)

Comment: I can't rely on the line number. Pure text. Editpad pro is basically notepad on steroids